# matlab - join cell strings keeping quotations

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

Assuming I have a cell of strings as follows:

```
ss = {'one', 'two', 'three'}
```

And I want to join these strings into 1 string. Use `strjoin` I got:

```
>> str = strjoin(ss, ', ')
str =
one, two, three
```

Is there any short way (1 - 2 lines of code) to keep all quotations `'`, as follows:

```
str = 'one', 'two', 'three'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try supplying [`sprintf`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of the strings contained in `ss`. In the [format specifier](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec) you can include the quotation marks, comma and space. The last comma and space need to be removed at the end.

```
result = sprintf('''%s'', ', ss{:}); %// cat the strings with quotes, comma and space
result = result(1:end-2); %// remove extra comma and space
```

Comment: I would have done it this way too, but you were faster :)

Comment: big thank to both Luis Mendo and rayryeng. Both answers work very nice. I accepted Luis's since it's the 1st, and for your 1 line code underneath.

Comment: @scmg - I would have acted the same way.  Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can perhaps use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) on your cell array of strings to insert a quotation before and after the string, then use `strjoin` on that:

```
ss = {'one', 'two', 'three'};
ss2 = regexprep(ss, '.+', '''$0''');
out = strjoin(ss2, ', ');
```

[`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) replaces strings in a cell array that match a pattern with something else.  In this case, I'm finding collecting the entire word with pattern `.+` then placing a single quotation before the word and after the word.  That is accomplished by `''$0''`.  Each pair of `''` is a single quotation.  I join the strings after by a comma separated by spaces.

We get:

```
out =

'one', 'two', 'three'
```

Comment: Uglier, but single line (based on this idea): `out = ['''' strjoin(ss, ''', ''') '''']`

Comment: @LuisMendo - OH that will work.  Definitely code golf worthy :) I will leave `regexprep` though for clarity.  Thanks for the idea!